# TypeError when trying to upload Pictures from Google App Engine to Picasa with the GData API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gdata-api, typeerror, picasa

I'm trying to write a small tool to upload Pictures from Google App Engine to Picasa. Fetching the image works, but when i try to upload it i get the error "*TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be (encoded string without NULL bytes), not str*"

The Code basically looks like this:

```
def getfile(url):
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        return (result.content)
    logging.error ("[-] Error fetching URL: %s" % url)

def uploadpicture(comment,pic):
    album_url = '/data/feed/api/user/%s/album/%s' % (username, album)
    fname = "image.jpg"
    entry = gd_client.InsertPhotoSimple(album_url, fname, comment, pic, content_type='image/jpeg')

picurl = "http://brilliantleap.com/blog/frog.jpg"
pic = getfile(picurl)
comment = "Test"
uploadpicture(comment, pic)
```

The full Stacktrace is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/birt/stuff/google/appengine/ext/webapp/**init**.py", line 507, in **call**
    handler.get(*groups)

File "/home/birt/stuff/app_picasaupload/main.py", line 124, in get
    uploadpicture(comment, pic)

File "/home/birt/stuff/app_picasaupload/main.py", line 104, in uploadpicture
    entry = gd_client.InsertPhotoSimple(album_url, fname, comment, pic, content_type='image/jpeg')

File "/home/birt/stuff/app_picasaupload/gdata/photos/service.py", line 469, in InsertPhotoSimple
    content_type)

File "/home/birt/stuff/app_picasaupload/gdata/photos/service.py", line 398, in InsertPhoto
    os.path.exists(filename_or_handle): # it's a file name

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 171, in exists
    st = os.stat(path)

File "/home/birt/stuff/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1109, in **call**
    if not FakeFile.IsFileAccessible(path):

File "/home/birt/stuff/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1018, in IsFileAccessible
    normcase=normcase)

File "/home/birt/stuff/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 1036, in _IsFileAccessibleNoCache
    if os.path.isdir(logical_filename):

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 195, in isdir
    st = os.stat(path)

TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be (encoded string without NULL bytes), not str

Any Ideas ? :-)

Comment: It's impossible to say, without the actual code and a complete stacktrace.

Comment: Are you perchance using Python 3?  That's what the error message suggests.  The appengine SDK specifically supports (and the production version too of course;-) Python 2.5, not later versions at this time.

Comment: That's not the exception you originally said you were getting. As the exception implies, you appear to be trying to fetch an invalid URL.

Comment: Sorry Nick, i posted the wrong Stacktrace first - fixed :)

Comment: Alex: I'm starting the SDK explicitly with python2.5

Comment: can some one solve my problem related to this? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337519/upload-image-to-imgur-after-resizeing-in-pil?noredirect=1#comment41338042_26337519

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Solution to this problem was using StringIO :-)

( http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html )

adding

```
pic = StringIO.StringIO(pic)
```

converts the result.content from urlfetch into a file-like format gdata expects.

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to unzip a string with the zipfile library and this did the trick.