# Upload Image To Imgur After Resizeing In PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imgur

I am writing a script which will get an image from a link. Then the image will be resized using the `PIL` module and the uploaded to Imgur using `pyimgur`. I dont want to save the image on disk, instead manipulate the image in memory and then upload it from memory to Imgur.
The Script:

```
from pyimgur import Imgur
import cStringIO
import requests
from PIL import Image

LINK = "http://pngimg.com/upload/cat_PNG106.png"
CLIENT_ID = '29619ae5d125ae6'
im = Imgur(CLIENT_ID)

def _upload_image(img, title):
    uploaded_image = im.upload_image(img, title=title)
    return uploaded_image.link

def _resize_image(width, height, link):
    #Retrieve our source image from a URL
    fp = requests.get(link)
    #Load the URL data into an image
    img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.content)
    im = Image.open(img)
    #Resize the image
    im2 = im.resize((width, height), Image.NEAREST)
    #saving the image into a cStringIO object to avoid writing to disk
    out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
    im2.save(out_im2, 'png')
    return out_im2.getvalue()
```

When I run this script I get this error: `TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`
Anyone has a solution in mind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError when trying to upload Pictures from Google App Engine to Picasa with the GData API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715574/typeerror-when-trying-to-upload-pictures-from-google-app-engine-to-picasa-with-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715574/typeerror-when-trying-to-upload-pictures-from-google-app-engine-to-picasa-with-t), and the solution is to use StringIO.

A common tip for searching such issues is to search using the generic part of the error message/string.

Comment: How about   im2.save(out_im2, format="PNG")  ? I am referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string